# Flutter firestore data returning null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have one application. In this I am making query for location data. Below is my code and firebase structure. But I am getting data null. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

```
GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: 28.535517, longitude: 77.391029);
    stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
      var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('Salons');
      return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
          center: center,
          radius: rad,
          field: 'position',
          strictMode: true);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Your Firestore document data structure doesn't follow the example given on the geoflutterfire package: https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire

Comment: @JoãoSoares Its pretty same..I have added data with add method as provided sample. Still its returning null.

Comment: Which package are you using, the one I linked above?

Comment: yes I used this package. and add data like
_firestore
        .collection('Salons')
        .add({'name': 'random name', 'position': myLocation.data});

Comment: @JoãoSoares any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I decode geohash `abc66ghh` with http://geohash.co/, it shows location 49.63150978, 170.63432693, a location in the Bering Sea.

When I encode latitude: 28.535517, longitude: 77.391029 with https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html, it shows geohash `ttp43` and a location in Northern India.

[image: map showing the those places mentioned]

I'm not sure what range you are searching, but it seems unlikely that these places are close enough to match it. Given the `position` field in the screenshot you shared, it seems that something is going wrong in the encoding of the geohash.

Comment: I deleted entire data and added again programatically. Still showing data null

Comment: If the result of redoing everything is the same geohash values for the same lat/lon, then it makes sense that it still doesn't work.